# How to represent repetition of activities in Activity Diagram

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

I have a situation in which, for a given number, I have to repeat a couple of activity for as many time as the given number is. How can I represent this situation in UML using Activity Diagram? I thought I could use expansion regions but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most basic way to is a loop showing the repetition: use a [decision node](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-controls.html#decision-node) and a flow looping back to a [merge node](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-controls.html#merge-node).

Alternatively, you could represent the loop with an expansion region. Use the keyword <> and expansion nodes to link the inside of the region and its outside.  You can find an example in [section 6 of this article](http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2005_05/column4/)

However, in principle an expansion region is used to process a collection in input:

> If the value is **iterative**, the expansion executions must occur in
>   an iterative sequence, with one completing before another can begin.
>   The first expansion execution begins immediately when the
>   ExpansionRegion starts executing, with subsequent executions starting
>   when the previous execution is completed. **If the input collections**
>   are ordered, then the expansion executions are sequenced in the order
>   induced by the input collection. Otherwise, the order of the expansion
>   executions is not defined.